# Splash screen duration time automation Appium

Tags: appium

My spash screen gets displayed for few seconds on Android .Can i check the duration of the time of screen using appium code?

Please share the code for this.

Thanks
Akshat Jain

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. What have you tried? We are not going to do your work but we can help you from something that you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

you can't get the accurate time between the activities, but we can get approx time.

Regrading splash screen time will differ some different apps, since lot more background thread will be running. Once app gets the specific data then it will move other screen.

We can try to first the time interval between while your starting the splash screen till next screen display.